# PythonTeX cannot modify header or footer

Tags: fancyhdr, pythontex

Using PythonTex 0.18 i cannot change the header or footer. I followed the solution in [using-pythontex-py-with-fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230446/using-pythontex-py-with-fancyhdr/230492) but it still doesnt work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\rfoot{Right}

\begin{pycode}
print("\\lfoot{Left}")

\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the LaTeX code generated by Python is inside a TeX group. Fancyhdr now does local changes by default, so these will not take effect. However you can make them global with the following trick (`\globaldefs=1`). The extra pair of braces in the code is to prevent the `\globaldefs` to affect other `pycode`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\rfoot{Right}

\begin{pycode}
print("{\\globaldefs=1\\lfoot{Left}}")

\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works! :-)